# Ajax funciona al generar el APK pero al subir el AAB a google play deja de funcionar

Tags: ajax, cordova, apk

Tengo una app funcionando con cordova web browser, realiza llamadas con ajax. Cuando genero el apk y lo instalo en un movil android funciona perfectamente, pero cuando genero el aab y lo subo a google play las llamadas de ajax dejan de funcionar, quedan bloqueadas.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido solucionarlo.

En el config.xml en  he añadido:

```
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```